# Rspec stub action variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

let's assume i have this code

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_methode
    some_var = some_value
    render text: some_var
  end
end
```

now, in Rspec i want to test the controller with different values.
how do i assign `some_other_value` to `some_var`?
i looked at [stub](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) but it doesnt work. i tried:

```
assign(:some_var, some_other_value )
controller.some_methode.stub(some_var: some_other_value )
some_methode.stub(some_var: some_other_value )
controller.some_methode.stub!(some_var: some_other_value )
controller.some_methode.stub(:some_var).and_return(some_other_value )
```

none of them works. `some_var` doesn't changes to `some_other_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test that `some_var` is assigned the value `some_value`, then you can use `assigns` (which I notice is not in your list):

```
it "assigns some_value to some_var" do
  get :some_method
  assigns(:some_var).should == some_value
end
```

However, if what you want to do is to actually *override* the assignment of `some_value` to `some_var`, then my advice would be to rethink (and possibly refactor) your controller code. I don't believe this is possible in rspec, but even if it is I don't think it's the right thing to do here.

If the value `some_value` is something that will change, then better to create a controller method for it and stub that method.

For example, in your controller code create a method `get_value` and assign `some_var` to that:

```
def some_method
  some_var = get_value
  render text: some_var
end

private

def get_value
  some_value
end
```

Then you can stub `get_value` in your spec:

```
it "does something when some_var is assigned value_to_test" do
  controller.stub(:get_value).and_return(value_to_test)
  get :some_method
  ... should ...
end
```

If on the other hand `some_value` is coming from the `params` hash, then you can control that by changing what is passed in to the call to the HTTP action:

```
it "does something when passed value_to_test" do
  get :some_method, :some_var => value_to_test
  ... should ...
end
```

This will set `params[:some_var]` to be `value_to_test` in your controller action.

For more on this see also [this discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/180028) (a bit old but relevant).

Comment: weird that you can stub instans vars but not regular vars. i ended up refactor it as you suggested. thanks